# Why is REL not detected in a jQuery attribute selector

Tags: jquery

If I use the following selector I get no results

```
$(".itemSearchModule .cmsItemList[rel='myRelValue']")
```

for the following html snippet

```
<div class="itemSearchModule">
    <ul class="cmsItemList" rel="myRelValue">
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**MISTAKE**
I was using firebug to debug the code and it seems that using that code in firebugs watch window is what is causing it to break

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure that element is already in the DOM when you call jQuery?

Comment: Hmm are you using 1.3.2? cause $(".itemSearchModule .cmsItemList]") definately exists with an appropriate rel, and I get a returned list of 0 when I use above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`rel` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel) is only allowed for [`A`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A) and [`LINK`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK) elements as it describes the relation between two documents, the current document and the document referenced in the `href` attribute. You should better use the `class` or `id` attribute for your purpose.

Comment: It will still work with jQuery, although not technically valid markup.

Comment: But surely in XHTML I can have any attribute on any element, if I have a bespoke one [myattr='test'] it will work, just why is REL blocked?!

Comment: Technically you can't have the rel tag. Run it through a validator and you'll get an error.

Comment: I understand that it doesn't work for you. But look at some of the comments to your question. I do this all the time as well.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's valid you should still be able to set attr('rel') and retrieve it using the selector syntax as then there is no invalid markup anywhere, only an attribute stored against the element in the DOM!

Answer (score 0):

It works :) You just need to "call" it this way:

`$('.itemSearchModule .cmsItemList[rel=myRelValue]')`

Check the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue) on jQuery.com

Also, don't forget to call the selector after page load

`$(document).ready(function () { put_selector_here });`

Comment: I dont see what difference your code is?! Im actually passing a string variable to it (code simplified for question), and the docs say quotes are optional